# How to change image next and previous using button clicklistener in android?

Tags: android, button, view

I have next and `previous button` for changing the image. When activity launch, image comes from `previous activity`. I use bundle object for getting image on my `current activity`. Actually 2 images use for pass it on bundle(image_a_inner and image_a_outer). One image overlap on second image and set on custom view. Now i want to when any image comes from bundle then i press next button or previous button then according to position image will be change. For example, images like A_Z alphabet. When i press on D image then it display on my activity using bundle and when i press next button then E image will be shown or when i press previous button then C image will be shown. Below is my code.

```
private DrawingView mDrawingView;

Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    int imageRes1 = extras.getInt("picture1");
    int imageRes2 = extras.getInt("picture2");
    mDrawingView = (DrawingView) findViewById(R.id.drawing_view);
    mDrawingView.setShape(imageRes1, imageRes2);
    btn_next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_next);
    //      btn_next.setOnClickListener(this);
            btn_next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    initializeMP();
                    playsound.start();




                    if(imageRes1==R.drawable.img_a_inner||imageRes2==R.drawable.img_a){
                        mDrawingView.setShape(R.drawable.img_b_inner, R.drawable.img_b);
                        index++;
                    }
                    else if(imageRes1==R.drawable.img_b_inner||imageRes2==R.drawable.img_b){
                        mDrawingView.setShape(R.drawable.img_c_inner, R.drawable.img_c);
                        index++;
                    }
                    else if(imageRes1==R.drawable.img_c_inner||imageRes2==R.drawable.img_c){
                        mDrawingView.setShape(R.drawable.img_d_inner, R.drawable.img_d);
                        index++;
                    }
                    else if(imageRes1==R.drawable.img_d_inner||imageRes2==R.drawable.img_d){
                        mDrawingView.setShape(R.drawable.img_e_inner, R.drawable.img_e);
                        index++;
                    }
                }
            });


    btn_prev = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_prev);

    //      btn_prev.setOnClickListener(this);
            btn_prev.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    initializeMP();
                    playsound.start();


                    if(imageRes1==R.drawable.img_b_inner||imageRes2==R.drawable.img_b){
                        mDrawingView.setShape(R.drawable.img_a_inner, R.drawable.img_a);
                        index--;
                    }
                    else if(imageRes1==R.drawable.img_c_inner||imageRes2==R.drawable.img_c){
                        mDrawingView.setShape(R.drawable.img_b_inner, R.drawable.img_b);
                        index--;
                    }
                    else if(imageRes1==R.drawable.img_d_inner||imageRes2==R.drawable.img_d){
                        mDrawingView.setShape(R.drawable.img_c_inner, R.drawable.img_c);
                        index--;
                    }
            });

        }
```

Comment: Try to pass all image as int array and also pass current index then try move next and previous base on button click.

Comment: i already try it but not success. image change one time after comparing on next button click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have lists for all images in advance, declare them as arrays.

Otherwise, you can pass them using bundle with getIntArray() and putIntArray().

Now, you have lists of images like this,

```
// These are can be declared as member or static variables.
int[] innerPictures = {R.drawable.image_a_inner, R.drawable.image_b_inner, ...}
int[] pictures = {R.drawable.image_a, R.drawable.image_b, ...}
```

or

```
int[] innerPictures = extras.getIntArray("innerPictures");
int[] pictures = extras.getIntArray("pictures");
```

And you need the index of image to be displayed at the first time, it can be also passed as a extra

```
int displayingIndex = extra.getInt("pictureIndex"); // it has to be member variable to use inside of listener
```

So code is like below,

```html
private DrawingView mDrawingView;

Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

int[] innerPictures = ...
int[] pictures = ...

displayingIndex = extra.getInt("pictureIndex");

mDrawingView = (DrawingView) findViewById(R.id.drawing_view);
mDrawingView.setShape(innerPictures[displayingIndex], pictures[displayingIndex]);
btn_next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_next);

            btn_next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                 
                    initializeMP();
                    playsound.start();

                    if (displayingIndex + 1 == innerPictures.length) return;
                    displayingIndex++;
                    mDrawingView.setShape(innerPictures[displayingIndex], pictures[displayingIndex]);
                }
            });


btn_prev = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_prev);

            btn_prev.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    initializeMP();
                    playsound.start();

                    
                    if (displayingIndex == 0) return;
                    displayingIndex--;
                    mDrawingView.setShape(innerPictures[displayingIndex], pictures[displayingIndex]);
            });

        }
```

Sorry for bad indentation.

Comment: i got java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=27; index=2130837574 using this code

Comment: I wrote for an example for you, it is not intended to use as it is. Anyway, it seems you have a problem with displayingIndex, show me stacktrace and code.

Comment: i used following code for button next:   if (imageRes1 + 1 == img_inner.length) return;
     imageRes1++;
                 mDrawingView.setShape(img_inner[imageRes1], img_simple[imageRes2]);

Comment: and on oncreate() i put this code: mDrawingView.setShape(img_inner[imageRes1],img_simple[imageRes2]);

Comment: Why do you have imageRes2? I thought images are used as a pair like image_a_inner and image_a, and thus you need a variable for a index not two indexes. If you want to use two variables you have to retrieve not one of them but both of them from bundle and manipulate both of them proprely in listeners. I mean you need to add and minus both of them in listeners if you want to use two indexes for inner image and another image separately. Also, check array bound for both.

Comment: imageRes2 is second(Overlapping) image on imageRes1. I set it on mDrawingView(imageRes1,imageRes2). Both imageRes1 and imageRes2 comes from bundle object and i set it on onCreate(). So please give me updated code accordingly to it.

Comment: I have questions for you, I understand what you are saying, however is imageRes2 really necessary? Do image_inner and image_simple have different lengths? When a next or prev button clicked, can only one of images be changed? If answer is no, I would suggest you use a variable for indexes.

Comment: actually i develop painting apps, so i used two images for drawing color over it. One image has border only and other is transparent. If i don't use imageRes2 means second image then color is not properly drawing on it. So i strickly use two images for achieve it.

Comment: image_inner and image_simple have same lengths, when next and prev button click then two images are set on mDrawingview's shape method.

Comment: My suggestion is same with earlier comments, Use a single variable for indexes for image array! Because arrays have same lengths, and the images are set as a pair.

Comment: Why don't use a imageRes instead of imageRes1 and imageRes2, like mDrawingView.setShape(img_inner[imageRes], img_simple[imageRes]);, it is no harm, and I think it will perfectly work! Because the indexes for img_inner and img_sample should be same, then why use separate variables?

Comment: because of using imageRes1 border image should comes and using imageRes2 transparent black image should comes from previous activity.

Comment: When button clicked, can imageRes1 and imageRes2 have different values?

Comment: no, imageRes2 overlaps on imageRes1. Two images on same size not different size.

Comment: I'm talking about indexes, not images. You use imageRes1 and imageRes2 as indexes in the code you wrote in comments.

Comment: yes i used index as int type. When pressing button then index+1.

Comment: so when button clicked, can imageRes1 and imageRes2 have different values?

Comment: no, actually i compare imageRes1 and imageRes2 with drawable image on if condition, and after set index value to 0 to n(number of image).

Comment: Could you explain in more detail?